# IOS Accessing a Modal View in AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, presentmodalviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am trying to access a view in my AppDelegate.m.  I was using `self.window.rootViewController` to get a reference to the active ViewController however, when I create a modal view with `presentViewController` I am unable to access the newly presented view.  How do I obtain a reference to a modal view from the AppDelegate.m?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is `presentedViewController`:

```
UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the modal view controller was presented off the rootViewController, than you should be able to access it with the following command:

```
NSArray *childVCs = [self.window.rootViewController childViewControllers];
```

Your modal viewController will be one of the  objects in that array.